# Images are not working in my admin panel of Voyager?

Tags: laravel-5

When I update images in setting tab they are not updating? & How can I migrate voyager database.

Comment: Provide more information. Are you getting an error? What is your code?

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this:
Updated .env file:
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000

Fixed issue